# Converting string date into specific date time format

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, datetime

I have a date time format in a string like following:

start date:

```
2018/06/30 23:00
```

and end date:

```
2018/07/01 19:32
```

And now I would like to convert this string into format like this:

```
2017-02-11T19:58:18.918Z
```

Both the start and end date should be in this date - string format

I have tried something like this:

```
   var properStart = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(startdate, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz",
                                                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString();
   var properEnd = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(enddate, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz",
                                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString();
```

But this gives me an error like following:

```
Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

What am I doing wrong here??

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to parse this string:

```
"2018/06/30 23:00"
```

Specifying this format:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz"
```

That format doesn't match that string, so the parsing fails.  Parse from the format that the input is in:

```
var properStart = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(startdate, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm",
                                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Then *output* into the format you want:

```
var properStartOutput = properStart.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz");
```

Or, if you really want it all in one line:

```
var properStart = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(startdate, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm",
                                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz").
```

The point is that *parsing input* and *formatting output* are two different operations.